Error "No features contain non-null values of system:time_start" when charting time series in Google Earth Engine
I want to create a chart showing the yearly average Chlorophyll a over a given time span. However I have been getting the following error when trying to create a time series.
After looking at this previously answered question:
Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start". Landsat 8 Surface Temperature Time-Series Chart (Earth Engine)
I have come to the conclusion that the problem lies somewhere with not copying the "system:time_start" properties correctly.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve the error for my case?
var startYear = 2015;
var endYear = 2024;

// Define the time period for the image collection
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 1, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear, 1, 1);

//Make list with months
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

// Load Sentinel-2 image collection and filter according to the ROI and time period
var S2collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
                  .filterBounds(region)
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5);

// Clip the filtered collection by the region of interest
var S2collection = S2collection.map(function(image) {
  return image.clip(region).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
});
                  
// Add NDWI band to image collection
  var addNDWI = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI')).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
  }; 

//Add NDCI to image collection
var addNDCI = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDCI')).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
  }; 

  // Function to mask out NDWI
  var S2maskedWater = function(image) {
   var NDWI = image.select(['NDWI']);
    return image.addBands(ee.Image(1).updateMask(NDWI.gt(0.15)).rename('NDWI_mask')).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
  };
  
S2collection = S2collection.map(addNDWI).map(S2maskedWater);


// Fucntion to mask land
var maskBands = function(image) {
  return image.select(['B2','B3','B4','B5', 'B8','NDWI']).updateMask(image.select('NDWI_mask')).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};

// map over the collection and use the function
var maskedCollection = S2collection.map(maskBands).map(addNDCI);

// Function add chla band
var addChla = function(image) {
  var chla = ee.Image(0).expression(
   '14.039 + 86.115  * NDCI  + 194.325 *  NDCI **2', {
     'NDCI': image.select('NDCI')
    });
  return image.addBands(chla.rename('Chla')).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};

var maskedCollection = maskedCollection.map(addChla);


//Make list with years
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);

// Map a function to select data within the year and apply mean reducer
var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
      return maskedCollection
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
        .set('year', y);
    }));


print(byYear, "byYear");

var yearChart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .series({
          imageCollection: byYear.select('Chla_mean'),
          region: region,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 30,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average Chla Conc Zeeland',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Average Chla Concentraion Per Year',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 2,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
        
print(yearChart);



Code access is below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/74a422e1840abe1b863fa2ef84ea5446?noload=true

You can fix that issue by adding a couple of lines of code when defining your byYear variable.
Since you are reducing a collection of images however, I am not sure which date you would like to copy exactly, so I am proposing two alternatives:
The first option involves copyProperties, arbitrarily taking the start date of the first image in the filtered collection:
var byYear = ee.ImageCollection(years.map(function(year) {
  var filteredCollection = maskedCollection
   .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
  return filteredCollection
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    .set('year', year)
    .copyProperties(filteredCollection.first(),['system:time_start']);
}));

The second option involves creating a bespoke date from the year in question:
var byYear = ee.ImageCollection(years.map(function(year) {
  var filteredCollection = maskedCollection
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
  var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1) 
  return filteredCollection
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
    .set('year', year)
    .set('system:time_start', date)
}));

